# Openlayer 3 coordinates

Tags: dictionary, coordinates, coordinate-systems, openlayers-3

I have a latitude and longitude of some point. How to conver its to the OpenLayer **3** map coordinate system?
My code is:

```
...requiries...


    var coord = [55.7522200, 37.61556005];
    //coord =  ol.proj.transform(coord,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON(
         ({
          object: {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'crs': {
              'type': 'name',
              'properties': {
                'name': 'EPSG:3857'
              }
            },
            'features': [
              {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                  'type': 'Point',
                  'coordinates': coord
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }));

    ...
    var map = ...
```

Could you gave me an example for converting the **var coords** on **JavaScript**.
You can see this example of code at link http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/geojson.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a coordinate `[lon, lat]` (in that **order**) you can transform it using:

```js
var newCoord = ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

Comment: thanx, i've mistake: mixed with latitude longitude.

Comment: It is ol.proj not ol.projection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var Coord = ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```